# Unable to load thymleaf template in Spring boot App

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, maven, template-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEo5d.png)

I have created a new Spring Boot app & trying to run on localhost, my project is running successfully but thymleaf template engine fails to load templates.

I have attached my project hierarchy screenshot. anyone can help regarding that ?

1. added thymleaf dependency
   2.added templates in templates folder
2. added class Path in application. Properties.
3. project maven updated, build & run successful.

Comment: Please show us your pom.xml file. If you are using spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf you shouldn't need to add the thymeleaf dependency nor modify the classpath, nor change any Spring properties.